# Balls and bins problem with 5 labelled balls and 3 labelled bins

Tags: probability

Suppose we throw 5 labelled balls randomly into 3 labelled bins.
a) What is the probability that the first bin is empty?
b) What is the probability that at least two bins are empty?

I know that the sample space is k^n, in this case being 3^5, but I can't figure out how I can solve these 2.

Comment: Recognize that this can be rephrased as asking about functions from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$, or equivalently as ternary sequences of length $5$.  Recognize that each function/sequence is equally likely to occur.  You correctly calculated that there are $3^5$ total such sequences.  For a) How many ternary sequences of length $5$ have no $1$'s?  Use your product rule or relate this to talking about functions $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\{2,3\}$.  For b) Recognize that "at least two bins are empty" implies all balls are in the same bin.  How many sequences have all entries the same?

Answer (score 0):

Label the bins A,B,C

example a/ grants P(No balls land in A)=P(All balls land in B or C)=$(2/3)^5$

example b/ is a little more tricky, P(at least two bins are empty) = P(A is full) + P(B is full) + P(C is full) $= 3 \cdot (1/3)^5$

Answer (score -1):

**a) the first bin is empty:**

you can fill the other two bins in 6 ways (we will consider only bin 2 because after choosing balls for bin 2, we have to put the rest of the balls in bin 3):

i) 5 balls in bin 2 and 0 balls in bin 3, you can do it in $^5C_5 = 1$ way

ii) 4 balls in bin 2 and 1 balls in bin 3,you can do it in $^5C_4 = 5$ way

iii) 3 balls in bin 2 and 2 balls in bin 3,you can do it in $^5C_3 = 10$ way

iv) 2 balls in bin 2 and 3 balls in bin 3,you can do it in $^5C_2 = 10$ way

v) 1 balls in bin 2 and 4 balls in bin 3,you can do it in $^5C_1 = 5$ way

vi) 0 balls in bin 2 and 5 balls in bin 3,you can do it in $^5C_0 = 1$ way

In total = (1+5+10+10+5+1) = 32 ways to keep the 1st bin empty.

Now the probability will be $$\frac{32}{3^5}$$.

**(b) at least two bins are empty**
it has two cases:

case-1 : only two bins are empty

case-2 : more than two bins (three here) are empty.

case-1: two bins are empty that means one bin is full. We can choose one bin from the 3 bins in $^3C_2 = 3$ way.

case -2: All the three bins are empty this can be done by only $1$ way.

so the probability of at least two bins empty $$=\frac{3+1}{3^5}=\frac{4}{3^5}$$

Comment: It is impossible for all three bins to be empty.  Also, your calculation for $32$ is incredibly tedious and can be done in a single step by following my outline above... $32=2^5$.